# remove image extension by preg_match before showing

Tags: php

I need to remove image extension by preg_match before showing. 
Initially, I used pattern **/(?:[^.]+)/** to detect by dot but it works incorrectly when the image name contain dots.

How could I force it starts searching the dot from the end of the string? Or any better ideas?

Answer (score 3):

### You could make use of [`pathinfo()`](https://www.php.net/pathinfo) for accurate results.

A one-liner..

```
<?php
$imgname = 'someimg.tft.xyz.gif';
echo pathinfo($imgname)['filename']; //"prints" someimg.tft.xyz
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/103714)

Comment: +1 for that. I just remenbered that function when I was notified about ac omment here and re-read the question, glad somebody else was faster with it, as it's clearly the best solutin in my eyes.

Comment: nice, only someone with more experience than me could've got this, I'm still practically a noob

Comment: For OO-obsessed people, there is the `SplFileInfo` class BTW: http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getbasename.php

Answer (score 2):

You could use `/[^.]+$/` to remove anything behind the last dot. The `$` matches "end of string" (on a sidenote: a `^` can be used to match "start of string").

If you set the capturing-group to "non-capturing" anyway, there is no need to include it BTW, works fine without any parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

For web compatible image formats you could use:

```
/^.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$/
```

Or you can use your pattern adding a $ at the end:

```
/(?:[^.]+$)/
```

Comment: YOu should include svg in the web-compatible format regexp :)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a regex for this, couldn't you just do this?;

```
$fileNamePieces = explode(".", $fileName);
array_pop($fileNamePieces);
$fileName = implode(".", $fileNamePieces);
```

however, if you insist on using a regular expression, here's one I just came up with;

```
^.+\.\D{2,4}$
```

also, [here](http://regexpal.com/)'s a website i use to test my regexes, in case you need to test your regexes

FINALLY (silly us), php has a built in function for this; [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) gives you the filename as well as the extension.

Comment: Even easier: `$withoutExtension = substr($fileName, 0, strrpos($filename, '.'))`

Comment: That regexp works differently than the one the OP specified. It MAY be suitable, but we don't know. FIleextensions don't always need to have 2-4 chars, they can be eny length... just that there are no common one for images doesn'T mean they don't exist. No criticism on this answer, just a comment.

Comment: yup I realized that, but I figured the OP can adjust the length, or just replace it with a `+` altogether since he/she knows regexes

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working

```
$file = "flower.rose.red.jpg";
$filename = substr($file, 0, strrpos($file, '.'));
$extension = substr($file, strrpos($file, '.'));
$img = str_replace($extension, '', $file);
echo $img;
```

OUTPUT:  flower.rose.red

Comment: erm... when you already extracted the filename, why look for the extension just to use it to delte it from the full filename again? Oo that doesn't make any sense. Line 2 alone is sufficient., see my comment on some other answer here.

Comment: why do you come after my answer and then post a noob version of my initial answer?